# Slashes instead of quotes in JavaScript string replace method

Tags: javascript, replace

Why do they use

**/**

instead of

**'**

in JavaScript string replace()? E.g.:

```
document.write(str.replace(/hi/, "hey"));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because // denotes a Regex, which is a much more powerful version of string searching/replacing than a simple Replace("x","y")

But also supports simple patterns.

```
var a = "xxx";
var b = a.replace(/x/,'y');
alert( b ); //alerts "yxx"
```

adding the g modifier to replace globaly would be:

```
b = a.replace(/x/g,'y');
alert(b); //alerts "yyy"
```

You can also add the i modifier to make it case-insensitive.

```
var a = "XXX";
b = a.replace(/x/gi,'y');
alert(b); // alerts "yyy";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Good, comprehensive answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaScript method `replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/replace) allows both a plain string and a [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as the search part.

And in your example a regular expression is used ([RegExp literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_a_Regular_Expression)) although a plain string would suffice.